# PHP: utf8_encode is causing a load of random characters to be added to a cel

Tags: php

Here's a snippet of code:

```
if (($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) !== false) {
            while (($line = fgetcsv($handle, 8192, ",")) !== false && $i <= 3) {
                $a[] = array_map("utf8_encode", $line );
                $i++;
            }
      }
```

However in some cells. I then dump that array to a CSV. All works fine except some odd characters are being added in one specific cell:

```
ÃƒÂƒÃ‚ÂƒÃƒÂ‚Ã‚ÂƒÃƒÂƒÃ‚Â‚ÃƒÂ‚Ã‚ÂƒÃƒÂƒÃ‚ÂƒÃƒÂ‚Ã‚Â‚ÃƒÂƒÃ‚Â‚ÃƒÂ‚Ã‚ÂƒÃƒÂƒÃ‚Â
```

On each save, more and more is concatenated until we have around 32k characters in the cell/field

ANy ideas what could be causing it or how we can get rid?

[image]

Comment: [utf8_encode — Encodes an ISO-8859-1 string to UTF-8](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) idea: your input strings are not  ISO-8859-1, look at the input. See also [this](https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html), found by googling 'Ãƒ utf8' :).

Answer (score 2):

`utf8_encode`, despite its tempting name, is not an automatic "fix UTF-8 issues" function, and there's a high chance it's not the function you actually want.

It's actual purpose is to convert text in one specific encoding (ISO 8859-1) into a different encoding (UTF-8). If your input is not in that encoding, it will just corrupt your text in confusing ways. Running it multiple times on the same data will make it more and more corrupted, as you have found.

So my advice is to remove that function, go back to the source data, and look more carefully at what encoding issues you're actually facing.

Remember to always ask "what encoding do I currently have?" as well as "what encoding do I want?" Since running any conversion will change the answer to "what encoding do I have?" that hopefully makes it clear why running the same conversion function twice on the same data won't make sense.

Once you've identified the encodings involved, you can use general-purpose functions such as `iconv` or `mb_convert_encoding` to convert from one encoding to another.